# JSON Get Object Names within Array with Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have a JSON response from an API call and I'm attempting to count the number of success objects and error objects within the results array in my example below. I've attempted to use the jackson object mapper which I can use to get the value assigned to an object but I want to either print every object name or count each object name within the array.

Below is my example JSON.

```JSON
{
  "errorCode": "36084",
  "message": "Completed with error(s).",
  "details": {
    "error-offsets": [
      0
    ],
    "results": [
      {
        "error": {
          "errorCode": "36084",
          "message": "Provided state does not exist: OhioLL.",
          "requestDetails": [
            {
              "region": {
                "qualifier": "Midwest"
              },
              "state": {
                "qualifier": "OhioLL"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "success": [
          {
            "region": {
              "qualifier": "Southeast"
            },
            "driver": {
              "qualifier": "Florida"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired results:

error
success

or

Errors=1
Successes=1

Answer (score 0):

Below code would give you the count of error and success objects:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String json = """
{
  "errorCode": "36084",
  "message": "Completed with error(s).",
  "details": {
    "error-offsets": [
      0
    ],
    "results": [
      {
        "error": {
          "errorCode": "36084",
          "message": "Provided state does not exist: OhioLL.",
          "requestDetails": [
            {
              "region": {
                "qualifier": "Midwest"
              },
              "state": {
                "qualifier": "OhioLL"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "success": [
          {
            "region": {
              "qualifier": "Southeast"
            },
            "driver": {
              "qualifier": "Florida"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
"""

int errorCount = 0
int successCount = 0
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def response = slurper.parseText(json)

response.details.results.each { result ->
    if(result['error']) {
        errorCount++
    } else if(result['success']) {
        successCount++
    }
}

println("Errors=${errorCount}")
println("Successes=${successCount}")
```

The output for the hardcoded JSON will be as below:

```
Errors=1
Successes=1
```